# Base64 String is not complete

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, base64

I have this snippet that captures a photo from a camera and output it in a base64 string.

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  console.log("Image Data: "+imageData);

  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  console.log("Src:" + smallImage.src);
}
```

When I look at the console log, the first log `Image Data` isn't complete, but the second `Src` log is longer.

Here is the log for `Image Data`:

```
09-18 17:00:24.591: D/CordovaLog(12097):
file:///android_asset/www/upload.html: Line 57 :
Image Data: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz
```

And for the `Src` I'm getting (You can decode it as well, nothing interesting):

```
09-18 17:00:24.630: D/CordovaLog(12097):
file:///android_asset/www/upload.html: Line 71 :
Src:data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

You can see by using the same variable `imageData` in both logs, I can't get the result to be the same.
And, if you decode the base64 string in `Src`, the image isn't complete.

Anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mQny/) showing the decoding of the base64

**EDIT**: `<img>` tag inside HTML body:

```
<img style="display:none;width:300px" id="smallImage" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use destination type as `FILE_URI` and get the base64 from the method described below

Setting destination type as FILe-URI is the recommended approach as you can see it in their docs

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Specify Destination Type as `FILE_URI` itself and in imagedata you will be getting the images file uri place it in a image tag and then place it inside HTML5 canvas and canvas has one method called toDataURL where you will be able to get the base64 of the corresponding image.

check the below code

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData)
     {

                var $img = $('<img/>');
                $img.attr('src', imageData);
                $img.css({position: 'absolute', left: '0px', top: '-999999em', maxWidth: 'none', width: 'auto', height: 'auto'});
                $img.bind('load', function() 
                {
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = $img.width();
                    canvas.height = $img.height();
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage($img[0], 0, 0);
                    var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                });
                $img.bind('error', function() 
                {
                    console.log('Couldnt convert photo to data URI');
                });

    }
```

Comment: Can it be in jpeg too? I've changed the destination type to FILE_URI in the capturing method. Here is what I got in `dataUri`: `09-18 17:41:54.717: I/Web Console(14740): dataUridata:, at file:///android_asset/www/upload.html:87` Do I need to do something with the `<img/>` tag inside HTML?

Comment: yes..it can be in jpeg..in the img tags src place this file:///android_asset/www/upload.html:87

Comment: didn't get...so what you want?

Comment: Just wanna show how my `<img>` looks like. Anyway, I don't get it, what do you mean by placing the file upload.html in the img tag?

Comment: no you dont need to add img in html...could you please check my code..where i am dynamicaly creating an img tag and in he second line i am specifying the src of the image file to the image data

Comment: I didn't get the `dataURI` correctly. The `imageData` is correct though. It is a path from my storage `imageData: file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.xxx.camerajson/cache/1379498647937.jpg at file:///android_asset/www/upload.html:89`. But I couldn't get the base64 string from `canvas.toDataURL()` as you said earlier :(

Comment: so what is the src rt now?is it file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.xxx.camerajson/cache/1379498647937.jpg? and what is the value you are getting in var datauri?

Comment: Var dataURI is only `data:`. Why is this happening?

Comment: i have answered this in another forum also..chk out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861965/how-to-upload-file-uri-using-google-drive-api-insert-file/18863973?noredirect=1#comment27867424_18863973

Comment: Okay I got it. But, the output doesn't give me a complete image: http://pastebin.com/TExQCeuJ I think it only capture the canvas, without the image captured.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37629/discussion-between-amnbhrm-and-arun-bertil)