# Passing a Cordova camera.getPicture File to AWS S3 (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3, cordova-plugins, fileapi

I am trying to pass an image created by Cordova's [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) to Amazon Web Service's S3.

In the past, I have [used the HTML File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to create my S3 params, and been able to pass the file object. I can't directly link to how you do this, but [there is an example on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) under the section 'example uses the HTML5 File API to upload a file on disk to S3'.

But this file has not been inserted by an input element, so I can't access anything like `files[0]` - the file is returned by Cordova either as a base64 or an available file location. So I am trying to figure out how I would replicate that action using Cordova information.

The solution I have worked off of [is found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22276089/1886901) which results in the code below:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            var theBody = btoa(evt.target._result);
            var 3_params = {
               Bucket: 'the-Bucket',
               Key: 'the-Key',
               ContentType: file.type,
               Body: theBody
            }
            ...other S3 SDK code...
         };
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
   }
}
```

This process works, but:

1. I have to take `_result` (which is a base64) through [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) which means...
2. It is pretty slow.
3. [It results in larger file sizes than I should need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402329/base64-encoded-image-size)
4. It also requires that I use [getObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) instead of [getSignedURL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)
5. When I get each object, I then have to put it through [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) which means...
6. If I have several objects to get things go VERY slow

What I would like to do is send the actual file object instead of messing with this `base64`. Alternatively, I would take a better/smarter/faster way to handle the base64 to S3 process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the 'JavaScript Canvas to Blob' polyfill to create a blob from my Base64, and then send the returned Blob on to S3. Because it is now a blob instead of a coded string, I can use getSignedURL in the s3 APK to reference the image.

The only change from above is:

`var theBody = btoa(evt.target._result);`

Becomes

`var theBody = window.dataURLtoBlob(evt.target._result);`

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Answer (score 2):

For those who find this, there is a better way since the new features introduced in `XMLHttpRequest` and now we can use readers and `Blob` as a source.

The initial code now could be written using `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` method and passing `Blob` object as the body source:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
          var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: file.type });
          var 3_params = {
            Bucket: 'the-Bucket',
            Key: 'the-Key',
            ContentType: file.type,
            Body: blob
         }
         ...other S3 SDK code...
       };
       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
     }
   }
 }
```

More info can be found at [Cordova Blog - Transition off of cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html)